# Accessing a Groovy controller closure from another controller

Tags: grails, groovy

In our codebase we have a closure in a controller that looks like this:

```
def doComputation = {
    def someObject = SomeObject.read(params.long("objectId"))

    //some irrelevant logic

    def response = [importantVariable : importantInteger, someOtherVariable : someOtherInteger]
    render response as JSON
}
```

Of course this is generally called from the .gsp page, but is there a way to call it from a closure in a different controller? Like so:

```
def someOtherClosure = {
    //some more irrelevant logic
    
    def responseFromOtherClosure = doComputation(objectId : someLong)
    theValueIWant = responseFromOtherClosure.importantVariable

    //more logic
}
```

Comment: Even if you *could* it doesn’t mean you *should*. `doComputation` is currently responsible for too many things at different levels: computation and rendering are separate concerns. If there’s shared logic IMO it should be treated as such: pull it out for re-use.

Comment: "Even if you could it doesn’t mean you should." - There isn't really an `if` to it.  You can, but you also shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

> but is there a way to call it from a closure in a different
> controller?

There is.

The closures are just properties in the controller class and they are `public`.  Controllers are configured as Spring beans so you could (you shouldn't) inject a controller into another controller and then reference the closure properties from there.

I think that answers your question but there are no good reasons to do that.  The right solution will depend on some particulars but if you have 2 controller actions that need to share some logic, best practice is to move that logic into a service and inject that service into all the controllers that need it.

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, instead of invoking a controller's code directly from another controller (again, no good reason to ever do that) you might want the first controller to issue a [redirect](http://docs.grails.org/5.1.7/ref/Controllers/redirect.html) or a [forward](http://docs.grails.org/5.1.7/ref/Controllers/forward.html) which will lead to the second controller.